# Bokeh components render through jquery.success

Tags: jquery, bokeh

I'm trying to pass components back to an `jQuery.ajax` call, and then set the html.

Bokeh code:

```
layout = column(plot)
script, div = components(layout)
res_json = jsonify(dict(script=script, div=div))
return res_json, 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

Jquery

```
success: function(data) {
  $("#bokeh_script").html(data["script"]);
  $("#bokeh_div").html(data["div"]);
}
```

Yet I get this error:
[image]

I've done some reading and it seems like it might be a problem with the the order in which everything loads.  I was also curious if you can even pass a tag like `.html(<script>)` and have it still load? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bokeh the order of the rendering does matter, thus the ajax call has to render the div before the script:

```
success(function(data){
    $("#bokeh_div").html(data["div"]);
    $("head").append(data["script"]);
});
```